# Backup Database Mysql (wordpress) via FTP

Tags: backup, ftp, mysql, wordpress, data-backup

I can access to server only via FTP. I need to copy the data on server for to restore in another server. But this server is offline (not reachable to HTTP ,SSH , etc.) I can access in read-only via FTP. I have backed up the WordPress file. But how can I backup the DB MySQL with only the access via FTP?

Is it possible?

Answer (score -1):

No, you can not normally backup your mysql db via FTP. You could script something to make this possible, but it would require shell access which you do not have.

Are you sure you do not have access to your database in any other way ? Usually access is provided via a web interface like phpmyadmin. You could then use the webtool to export/backup your database.

Comment: This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. You can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment). Please read [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174).